# Ebean does not find Entities after creating JAR

Tags: java, entities, ebean

The problem is that in Eclipse-IDE every test with Ebean related methods works fine, but when you compile a jar-File to use it e.g. on a Homepage, or on command prompt, i only get this

```
Jul 10, 2012 4:25:48 PM com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.util.ClassPathSearch find
Classes
Warnung: No Entities found in ClassPath using ClassPathReader [com.avaje.ebeanin
ternal.server.util.DefaultClassPathReader@6c08bae7] Classpath Searched[[file:/C:
/xampp/htdocs/webp3/jars/DPG.jar]]
Jul 10, 2012 4:25:48 PM com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.BootupClassPathSearc
h search
Information: Classpath search hits in jars[] pkgs[]  searchTime[27]
Jul 10, 2012 4:25:48 PM com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool in
itialise
Information: DataSourcePool [mysql] autoCommit[false] transIsolation[READ_COMMIT
TED] min[1] max[25]
Jul 10, 2012 4:25:48 PM com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory
 setDatabasePlatform
Information: DatabasePlatform name:mysql platform:mysql
Jul 10, 2012 4:25:48 PM com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.subclass.SubClassManager$
1 run
Information: SubClassFactory parent ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoade
r]
Jul 10, 2012 4:25:48 PM com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorMana
ger logStatus
Information: Entities enhanced[0] subclassed[0]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.dpu.entit
ies.Department is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(Default
Server.java:1008)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(Default
Server.java:965)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.
java:1001)
        at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.find(Ebean.java:1143)
        at com.dpu.data.Datagenerator.generateData(Datagenerator.java:26)
        at com.dpu.main.MainGenerator.main(MainGenerator.java:23)
```

I tried many "solutions" on google like editing the Classpath, but everything seems to be fine regarding on the log.

```
My JAR-Manifest contains this:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.dpu.main.MainGenerator
Class-Path: .
```

Does someone know how to solve this silly problem? I tried everything this day and it's just annoying

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to user1537597's answer you can add

```
# specify jars to search for entity beans  
ebean.search.jars=myJarFile.jar
```

to the ebean.properties file, if you don't use the programmatic configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the following to ebean.properties

```
ebean.packages=com.packagename
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here.
The only way is to extract the jar and run the java main class. You need to put the ebean.properties file in the root of your project too.

e.g.:

```
jar xf project.jar

cp /my_project_root/ebean.properties project

cd project

java Project
```

Answer (score 0):

not it depends on the fact that you need to specify in the ebean.properties to look for entities in the jar. I'm looking how to do it from the property file. Now I only found with the programmatic configuration.

config.addJar("nameFile.jar")

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using a programmatic configuration and adding every entity class manually like this:

```
serverConfig.addClass(Entity.class);
```

The advantage of this approach compared to `ebean.search.jars=yourJar.jar` is that if the jar file name changes, it will still work.